# Retries using HTTPRoundTripper

Tags: http, go

Is [`http.RoundTripper`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) the right place to implement a retry mechanism for http GET requests based on HTTP status codes (e.g. 429) in Go?

It somehow "feels right" ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qwxgzFKVIvR)) and does not change the existing interfaces to `http.Client` or `http.Request`/`http.Response`. However, the [documentation explicitly states](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper):

> RoundTrip should not attempt to interpret the response.

and

> RoundTrip should not modify the request, except for consuming and
>   closing the Request's Body.

Am I already interpreting responses by evaluating HTTP status codes and/or modifying requests by resending failed HTTP requests when I use `http.RoundTripper` for doing so and, therefore, work against the original intention of `http.RoundTripper`? Why is it a bad idea (if so)?

Comment: If the server says `Retry-After: 60`, your `RoundTripper` and thus `client.Get()` will wait 60 seconds. That doesn't feel right at all to me.

Comment: From my perspective, retries should be dealt with explicitly in your application. The risk of modifying Roundtripper is that you hide the retry logic at the position in your code where it matters most: when someone (including you, after 6 months) tries to find out what the application does.The risk being explicitly that the retry logic is missed, and someone comes along seeing code which implicitly assumes the request is successful - and writes a retry logic/error handling at a different point in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, you are completely right! However, this question is more on how and if I can use `http.RoundTripper` for doing so. That's why excluded the implementation at all.

Comment: Thank you, @MarkusWMahlberg. Would you mind to post it as an answer?

Comment: Well, you can, as you demonstrated yourself. But imho, it is a bad idea.

Comment: @MichelDorner Done, see below.

Comment: "RoundTrip should not attempt to handle higher-level protocol details such as redirects, authentication, or cookies." I consider retries a higher-level feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my perspective, retries should be dealt with explicitly in your application.

The risk of modifying Roundtripper is that you hide the retry logic at the position in your code where it matters most: when someone (including you, after 6 months) tries to find out what the application does.

The risk being explicitly that the retry logic is missed, and someone comes along seeing code which implicitly assumes the request is successful - and writes a retry logic/error handling at a different point in the code.

**EDIT**

As for retry and backoff, I tend to use https://gopkg.in/cenkalti/backoff.v3, which makes it easy and concise to retry an operation

```
var (
   resp *http.Response
   err error
)

operation := func() error {
    resp, err = http.Get("http://example.com/")
    // Handle Retry-After here, if you wish...
    // If err is nil, no retry will occur
    return err
}

err := backoff.Retry(operation, backoff.NewExponentialBackOff())
if err != nil {
    panic("getting resource: permanent error during backoff")
}

// resp is non-nil
```

Comment: I totally can follow your logic (especially about the explicitness of failed/retried requests). But then the only purpose of this RoundTripper I can imagine is caching.

Comment: @MichaelDorner And do the actual RoundTrip ;) Seriously, another thing could be implementing an http based wire protocol. And implement http protocol versions to come.